# When the conversion from 10% to 0.1 should be done when storing percentages in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, percentage

I have column `progress` of type decimal. I want it to store the percentage of progress of something. The format I want to use is 0.1 for 10% because it makes easier the calculations with that column.

I want the user to input as 10% so my question is when the conversion from 10% to 0.1 should be done?

Answer (score 1):

With the MVC pattern, the Model should be responsible for manipulation of data and the Controller should just inform the Model of the user's input.

Therefore I would aim to manipulate the data in the Model via a callback:

```
before_save { |project| project.progress = project.progress.convert_percent_to_decimal }
```

Comment: I noticed this is your first post (welcome), one thing I'd add to this answer, which seems to be right by the way, is why you'd do it that way and what advantages are gained.

Comment: I thought to do it this way but I though 'What happens if I want to override the progress with another project's progress. Something like this: `a = Project.first; b = Project.last; a.progress= b.progress; a.save`. If `b.progress == 0.5` then `a.progress == 0.005`. That's why I wouldn't do it in the model.

Comment: It's hard for me to see why you would need to do that - because in my mind projects would be independent things. But if you needed to override it with another project - could you find a way for the user to submit that change to your project controller **update** action and then you use the same before_save callback?

Comment: what does the `convert_percent_to_decimal` method in the model look like?